# how to add my value into asp format

Tags: asp-classic

```
Dim adoRecordset
```

Remark is the value saved in SQL

my html value is

```
value="<%=adoRecordset("Remark")%>">
```

so how could i add it into the  `" ??? "`

```
response.Write  VALUE='???'
```

Thanks Guys ~

Comment: so you want to display adoRecordset("Remark") on HTML page ??

Comment: no , i want to  put the value="<%=adoRecordset("Remark")%>">   into response.Write "<VALUE= '???' name='test' >"

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do the trick for you:

```
Response.Write "<value='" & adoRecordset("Remark") & "' name='test'>"
```

**Edit**: My quick and lazy version, as done properly by Mr. Shadow Wizard

```
Response.Write("<input name=""test"" value=""" & Replace(adoRecordset("Remark"), """", "&quot;") & """ />")
```

Comment: To have valid HTML wrap with double quotes: `Response.Write("<input name=""test"" value=""" & Replace(adoRecordset("Remark"), """", "&quot;") & """ />")` this will also prevent breaking the value when there are double quotes in the remarks.

Comment: Thanks Shadow Wizard, I was being a bit lazy yesterday.